# $http.get - Data not fetching in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm an absolute beginner in AngularJs, I just created a simple angular js application to fetch details from MySQL database and display the same in an HTML page. While running the code I didn't get any response. Below are the HTML code, AngularJS script and PHP server side code I have written to do this. is there any wrong with my code? Thanks is an advance.

> AngularJS Script

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope) {
    $http.get("select.php")
    .success(function(data){
      alert("data retrieved");
    });
});

</script>
```

> HTML

```html
<form class="cf">
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="usercontroller">
  <div class="half left cf">
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" ng-model="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="text" ng-model="subject" id="input-subject" placeholder="Subject">
  </div>
  <div class="half right cf">
    <textarea name="message" ng-model="message" type="text" id="input-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>  
  <input type="submit" name="btnInsert" value="Add Data" id="input-submit">


  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.email}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>


</div>
</form>
```

> PHP

```
<?php 
//database settings
$connect = mysqli_connect("hostname", "root", "", "test");

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from contact");

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
    print json_encode($data);
 ?>
```

Comment: PHP working alright?

Comment: You may need to `return $data` rather than `print` it. and check you are  getting `select.php` file.

Comment: php script is working properly and replaced "print json_encode($data);" with "return json_encode($data);" , but the problem still exists. just showing a blank screen.